# Why does printf print random value with float and integer format specifier

Tags: c, floating-point, x86-64

I wrote a simple code on a 64 bit machine

```
int main() {
    printf("%d", 2.443);
}
```

So, this is how the compiler will behave. It will identify the second argument to be a double hence it will push 8 bytes on the stack or possibly just use registers across calls to access the variables. `%d` expects a 4 byte integer value, hence it prints some garbage value.

What is interesting is that the value printed changes everytime I execute this program. So what is happening? I expected it to print the same garbage value everytime not different ones everytime.

Comment: The memory in your machine is most definitely not going to be the same every time you run a program.

Comment: If I remember correctly, mismatch argument causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: The reason that a specific C implementation will print varying values in this situation is highly dependent on the implementation, including the specific version of the compiler, the target operating system, and the target processor. To get a definitive answer, you need to precisely identify these things. Also note that an answer might give some slight insight into how certain mechanisms, such as the program loader, work, or it might be completely uninteresting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's undefined behaviour, of course, to pass arguments not corresponding to the format, so the language cannot tell us why the output changes. We must look at the implementation, what code it produces, and possibly the operating system too.

My setup is different from yours,

> Linux 3.1.10-1.16-desktop x86_64 GNU/Linux (openSuSE 12.1)

with gcc-4.6.2. But it's similar enough that it's reasonable to suspect the same mechanisms.

Looking at the generated assembly (`-O3`, out of habit), the relevant part (`main`) is

```
.cfi_startproc
subq    $8, %rsp             # adjust stack pointer
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
movl    $.LC1, %edi          # move format string to edi
movl    $1, %eax             # move 1 to eax, seems to be the number of double arguments
movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0    # move the double to the floating point register
call    printf
xorl    %eax, %eax           # clear eax (return 0)
addq    $8, %rsp             # adjust stack pointer
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
ret                          # return
```

If instead of the `double`, I pass an `int`, not much changes, but that significantly

```
movl    $47, %esi            # move int to esi
movl    $.LC0, %edi          # format string
xorl    %eax, %eax           # clear eax
call    printf
```

I have looked at the generated code for many variations of types and count of arguments passed to `printf`, and consistently, the first `double` (or promoted `float`) arguments are passed in `xmmN`, `N = 0, 1, 2`, and the integer (`int`, `char`, `long`, regardless of signedness) are passed in `esi`, `edx`, `ecx`, `r8d`, `r9d` and then the stack.

So I venture the guess that `printf` looks for the announced `int` in `esi`, and prints whatever happens to be there.

Whether the contents of `esi` are in any way predictable when nothing is moved there in `main`, and what they might signify, I have no idea.

Comment: How do you know printf will not check the value of the floating point register inside when its called?

Comment: Because the format string says it should look for an `int`, those aren't passed in the floating point registers.

Comment: So u mean inside the printf implementation when it sees a "%d" it either pops some 4 byte value from stack or uses a register like %eax which are different across executions?

Comment: Yes, something like that. It depends of course on the implementation, there's nothing that forbids passing integer type arguments in floating point registers, but it's not done in my gcc (nor my clang, for that matter).

Comment: Although the questioner accepted this answer, this answer does not answer the question. The question specifically asks why the printed value changes. “It is undefined behavior” only tells us that the C standard does not define this behavior; it does not tell us what is happening. Typical multi-user operating systems sanitize the memory and registers of a process when creating the process (all contents come from the creating process, the executable, specific environment data, or are initialized to zero or specific values). Usually, this results in deterministic behavior. (Continued…)

Comment: Address space layout randomization (ASLR) is one source of varying behavior, but it is slightly surprising that this would manifest in the value printed by using `printf` in the way described in the question. (There could be some data from ASLR left lying around, but it is more likely that the stack or register where `printf` expects to find the integer argument contains some fixed value.) In any case, more information would be needed to answer this question, particularly the target operating system.

Comment: I am using linux 3.4.4-2. The distribution is arch linux and gcc version 4.7.1.

Comment: @mc_87 I have expanded the answer somewhat, explains some more, though the ultimate answer would need to be given by somebody familiar with the lower-level workings of the OS/the C runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This answer attempts to address some of the sources of variation. It is a follow-up to Daniel Fischer’s answer and some comments to it.

As I do not work with Linux, I cannot give a definitive answer. For a `printf` later in a large application, there would be a myriad of sources of potential variation. This early in a small application, there should be only a few.

Address space layout randomization (ASLR) is one: The operating system deliberately rearranges some memory randomly to prevent malware for knowing what addresses to use. I do not know if Linux 3.4.4-2 has this.

Another is environment variables. Your shell environment variables are copied into processes it spawns (and accessible through the `getenv` routine). A few of those might change automatically, so they would have slightly different values. This is unlikely to directly affect what `printf` sees when it attempts to use a missing integer argument, but there could be cascading effects.

There may be a shared-library loader that runs either before `main` is called or before `printf` is called. For example, if `printf` is in a shared library, rather than built into your executable file, then a call to `printf` likely actually results in a call to a stub routine that calls the loader. The loader looks up the shared library, finds the module containing `printf`, loads that module into your process’ address space, changes the stub so that it calls the newly loaded `printf` directly in the future (instead of calling the loader), and calls `printf`. As you can imagine, that can be a fairly extensive process and involves, among other things, finding and reading files on disk (all the directories to get to the shared library and the shared library). It is conceivable that some caching or file operations on your system result in slightly different behavior in the loader.

So far, I favor ASLR as the most likely candidate of the ones above. The latter two are likely to be fairly stable; the values involved would usually change occasionally, not frequently. ASLR would change each time, and simply leaving an address in a register would suffice to explain the `printf` behavior.

Here is an experiment: After the initial `printf`, insert another `printf` with this code:

```
printf("%d\n", 2.443);
int a;
printf("%p\n", (void *) &a);
```

The second printf prints the address of `a`, which is likely on the stack. Run the program two or three times and calculate the difference between the value printed by the first `printf` and the value printed by the second `printf`. (The second `printf` is likely to print in hexadecimal, so it might be convenient to change the first to "%x" to make it hexadecimal too.) If the value printed by the second `printf` varies from run to run, then your program is experiencing ASLR. If the values change from run to run but the difference between them remains constant, then the value that `printf` has happened upon in the first `printf` is some address in your process that was left lying around after program initialization.

If the address of `a` changes but the difference does not remain constant, you might try changing `int a;` to `static int a;` to see if comparing the first value to different part of your address space yields a better result.

Naturally, none of this is useful for writing reliable programs; it is just educational with regard to how program loading and initialization works.